How can I inverse-Laplace transform this?
I need to calculate the inverse-Laplace transform
$$\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r - \frac{r(1-c)}{(1-b\cdot r)^a-1}}\right)$$
for some parameters $a,b,c$. I can assume that $a,b$ are real with $a>0,a\ne1,b>0$ but $c\in\mathbb{C}$ is arbitrary.
I couldn't find the residues to do the contour integral.

Don't understand constraint $b>0$: E.g. for the case $a=2$ the poles of the expression are $r\to \frac{b\pm\sqrt{2 b^2-b^2 c}}{b^2}$. For stability condition $\Re(r)<0$ it is necessary that $b<0 \land c\ge 1$

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s-\frac{s (1-c)}{(1-b s)^a-1}}\right](t)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1-c}{s \left(-2+c+(1-b s)^a\right)}\right](t)=\\1+\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{m-a (1+m)} a (1-c) (-2+c)^m e^{-i
   a (1+m) \pi } (1+m) \Gamma \left(a+a m,0,-\frac{t}{b}\right)}{\Gamma (1+a+a m)}=\\1-(-1)^{-a} b^{-a} (-1+c) t^a \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((1)_m (a)_{a m+n}\right) \left(\frac{t}{b}\right)^n
   \left(-(-1)^{-a} b^{-a} (-2+c) t^a\right)^m}{\left(\Gamma (1+a) (a)_{a m} (1+a)_{a m+n}\right) (m! n!)}$$
for: $a>0$ and $b>0$
Double infinty series can by expressed by:Srivastava - Daoust function.
Mathematica code with Check:
f[a_, b_, c_, t_] := 1 + N[Sum[((-1)^(m - a (1 + m)) a (1 - c) (-2 + c)^
m E^(-I a (1 + m) \[Pi]) (1 + m) Gamma[a + a m, 0, -(t/b)])/
Gamma[1 + a + a m], {m, 0, 2000}], 10]; 
g[a_, b_, c_, t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s - (s*(1 - c))/((1 - b*s)^a - 1)), s, N@t]

{f[1/2, 1, 1 + I, 2], g[1/2, 1, 1 + I, 2]}

(*{0.3412734810 + 0.6337193227 I, 0.341273 + 0.633719 I}*)

How did you derive this? Use Mathematica code below.
Code can you executed for free Here you must only Sign In.
 Sum[Sum[(Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0, 
    Residue[Assuming[m \[Element] Integers && m >= 0, 
      Residue[InverseLaplaceTransform[
         MellinTransform[
           MellinTransform[A/(s (B + (W - b s)^a)), B , q] // 
            PowerExpand, W, q1] // PowerExpand, s, t]*
        B^(-q), {q, -m}]], {q1, -n}]] // FunctionExpand) /. 
 A -> 1 - c /. B -> -2 + c, {n, 0, Infinity}] // PowerExpand, {m, 0, Infinity}]
 (*Output is very similar but is correct*)


How did you derive this?

@user1747134 I update my answer.

What is the role of the Mellin Transform here? Is this relying on some theorem which relates it to the Laplace transform?

I mean, I need to understand why this Approach of doing Mellin transform on two variables, then Inverse Laplace and then ResiudeSum is justified? Is the ResidueSum meant as inverse Mellin? Why is it OK to put the inverse Lapalace in the middle just like this?

@user1747134  Yes, ResidueSum meant as inverse Mellin Transform.
